How to index custom database record with indexed_search in TYPO3?
How is it possible to index custom database records in TYPO3? I tried with indexed search, setting the option „Table to index“ to the corresponding database in the configuration. But this didn’t work. I couldn’t find help in the documentation. I also checked the extension ke_search, but also there couldn’t find how to index custom records. Any ideas how to do it?

You can use EXT:crawler to index custom records.
Configuration example:
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets {
   tx_news = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]=[_TABLE:tx_news_domain_model_news; _PID:57; _WHERE: hidden = 0]
   tx_news {
     pidsOnly = 58
   }
}

TER: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/crawler
Document: https://docs.typo3.org/p/tomasnorre/crawler/11.0/en-us/Introduction/Index.html
